# How to find the minimum and maximum element of the array?

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] m = new int[1000];
    int n = textBox1.Lines.Lenght;
    int i;
    int k = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    int average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            m[k] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Lines[i]);
            sum = sum + m[k];
            product = product * m[k];
            average = sum / n;
        }     
        catch 
        {
            MessangeBox.Show("Буквы нельзя!!");
            k++;
        }
    }

    label10.Text = n.ToString();
    label11.Text = sum.ToString();
    label12.Text = product.ToString();
    label13.Text = average.ToString();     
}
```

Comment: your question is little bit unclear. can you explain your problem more?

Comment: Use [Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the largest number or smallest number in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] m = new int[1000];
    int n = textBox1.Lines.Lenght;
    int i;
    int k = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    int average = 0;
    int min = Int32.MaxValue;   // will hold min value
    int max = Int32.MinValue;   // will hold max value

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            m[k] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Lines[i]);
            sum = sum + m[k];
            product = product * m[k];
            if (m[k] < min)
              min = m[k];
            if (m[k] > max)
              max = m[k];
        }     
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Буквы нельзя!!");
            k++;
        }
    }
    average = sum / n;  //Computing average here is more efficient
    label10.Text = n.ToString();
    label11.Text = sum.ToString();
    label12.Text = product.ToString();
    label13.Text = average.ToString();     
}
```

Caveat: If your array is empty, you may not want to have Int32.MaxValue and Int32.MinValue as your default min and max. You will need to handle that case separately.

Comment: This is the most efficient solution, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;



int[] m = new int[1000];

// fill in the array here .....

int min = m.Min(); // find the minimum

int max = m.Max(); // find the maximum
```

Comment: care to explain why there are down votes? He wants to know how to find minimum and maximum of the array.

Comment: I agree, that's the sort of answer I would be looking for!

Comment: No idea why it was downvoted. Have an upvote. :) However, it would be more efficient to compute the max and min in the existing loop in the OP's code rather than loop through all the elements an extra two times.